# PHP, call function on object in array

Tags: php, function, object

I have an array that contains objects.

How can i call object number 2 in the array´s function?

This code will work:

```
$people = $details->getPeople();
echo $people[2]->getName();
```

But there must be a "one liner" for this? Like (does not work):

```
$details->getPeople()[2]->getName();
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I believe that this may work in PHP 5.5.

Comment: `($details->getPeople())[2]->getName();` . That should work.

Comment: Not everything in PHP can be a one-liner.  That being said, the `getPeople()[2]` syntax wasn't added until PHP 5.4.  What version of PHP are you using?  If it's less than 5.4, then you cannot make a one-liner of this.  Remember: "Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semi-colons --[Alan Perlis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Perlis)"

Comment: Making it a 2 liner as you have it will make it far easier to debug when there is an error later on. Makes it easier to see whether your error appears when you try to pull details or when you try to get the name.

Comment: Thank you guys with the info...will upvote each of your comments because they each added some useful info. Thank you guys! I will make it a "two liner". Both for "easier code reading" and not to have to rely on v 5.4 +